# How should I change the database layout of my html form to make it more scalable?

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms, database-design

I have a HTML form which sends the results to a database currently. The questions are hardcoded to the html page and I am trying to make the form more scalable, dynamic and flexible.

I got suggested that I should have different tables for the questions, choices and submitted answers. I sketched out a layout in Excel and now I have written scripts for creating the tables but I am still facing a problem with the `question_choiceX` columns. What if someone needs to make a questions that has 36 possible answers? Or 100? Those are probably rare scenarios but I acknowledge that I can't ignore them when creating the database or I might run in to big problems later.

Since SQL doesn't have arrays, I have been thinking hard and I've realized one possible solution but I am not sure if it would be good practice, and it's not perfect either:

- Making the `question_choiceX` columns into only a single `question_choices` column which is a `FOREIGN KEY` that refers to another table dedicated for all of the possible choices of that single question. I'd imagine this not to be very optimal because then I might end up with an enormous amount of tables. And this doesn't help either if I need to add more answer choices to a question afterwards.

Comment: What do html forms have to do with database design?

Comment: _I got suggested that I should have different tables for the questions, choices and submitted answers...._ read over database normalization

Comment: Well, I am trying to design an optimal database for a html form.

Comment: Quizes have questions. Questions have multiple-Choise-Answers. Questions have one correct  answer.

Comment: _Well, I am trying to design an optimal database for a html form..._ No.. you should first design your database and then the frontend depending on your data

Comment: And the frontend data structure needn't match the database structure exactly, anyway. It's common to translate between the two. Design a correctly normalised database which can hold all of the data needed to represent the business processes you need. Then design some HTML forms to create a UI you think will be efficient and usable for your users. Then write some code to wire them up (including manipulation of the data into different structures, if necessary).

Comment: _Quizes have questions. Questions have multiple-Choise-Answers. Questions have one correct answer._ This is not a quiz, this is a survey asking for people's opinions so there is no one correct answer

Comment: _"Making the question_choiceX columns into only a single question_choices column which is a FOREIGN KEY that refers to another table dedicated for all of the possible choices of that single question. I'd imagine this not to be very optimal because then I might end up with an enormous amount of tables."_ . Not sure why you think this would lead you to have a lot of _tables_. And your questions table wouldn't contain this column anyway. You'd have a "choices" table which contains the the ID of its parent question as the foreign key field, pointing to the primary key in the questions table.

Comment: That way, if you have 4 choices for question 1, you'd have 4 rows in the "choices" table, all with question ID 1 in the foreign key column. Then for question 2 you might have 3 rows showing 3 different choices, etc. This is a correctly normalised, optimised design. (Of course if the same option needs to be used for more than one question, it gets more complicated (as per Quentin's answer below), but you didn't specify that as far as I can see.

Comment: Ah, now I understand. I have to join the tables with another table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are [many-to-many](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_(data_model)) relationship.

Have a table of questions. (One row per question).

Have a table of answers. (One row per answer). (You only need one table of answers, not one per question).

Have a bridge table between them which associates the answers with the question they are for.

Have a table of users or a table of attempts to answer the questions.

Have a bridge table between that and the answers.

Bridge tables generally have two foreign keys, one onto each of the tables they are bridging. You might use those two foreign keys as a composite primary key for the bridge table itself.

Comment: Thank you. Now I understand what I should do. That makes sense!